# Postgres query result into CSV in terminal wrongly quotes text values

Tags: database, postgresql, csv, terminal, psql

I am using following postgres command in terminal to output very large query result into CSV format:

```
psql -d ecoprod -t -A -F"," -f queries/query.sql > exports/output.csv
```

It works just fine except its not valid CSV format. Text values should be wrapped in quotes "". Its not and its causing many problems parsing the CSV when there are commas in the text and so on.

Of course I could use another delimiter like semicolon however its the similar problem. In addition some text values contain line break characters which also breaks the parsing.

Didnt find any way to modify the command in documentation. Hope you will help me. Thank you.

Comment: Use COPY ... WITH CSV instead of a select to get actual CSV output.

Comment: Add the content(**as text**) of `query.sql` to the question.  Use `--csv` instead of `-A` and drop `-F`.

Answer (score 0):

-F doesn't promise to generate valid CSV.  There is a --csv option you could use instead, which is at least intended for this purpose.  But it seems like COPY or \copy would be more suited.